# solution for solve the 409 conflict error in jmeter test

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter test, I have successfully correlated the authorization token in the header manager, however, the token expires every 6 hours. Despite this, the expiration is not being reflected and I am encountering a 409 conflict error.

[image]

I attempted to update the hardcoded value in the header manager that expires every 6 hours using JSON and regular expression elements, however, I encountered a 409 conflict error upon passing the hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 409](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409) description:

> The `HTTP 409 Conflict` response status code indicates a request conflict with the current state of the target resource.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. **For example, you may get a 409 response when uploading a file that is older than the existing one on the server**, resulting in a version control conflict.

Given you like "hardcoding" I suspect that correlation is either missing or incorrectly implemented in your test. It's not about wrong [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header, otherwise you would get [HTTP 401 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), it's rather an action which has another hard-coded parameter which was recorded as it is and it has to be dynamic.

More information: [How to Handle JMeter Correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)